# MySQL - Exclude all rows from one table if match on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the very fuzzy question but my problem is that I have three different tables. One table containing user information, one for the users posts and one for the users likes. I want to select data from the tables containing the users data and posts but only return a post that the user have not liked and not is posted by the user itself. I have tried to use different combinations of `JOINS` but with no success.

For example i want to select the rows for the user with id = 1.

```
Table users:
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        A |
|  2 |        B |
|  3 |        C | 
+----+----------+

Table posts:
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |       1 |
|  3 |       2 | 
|  4 |       3 | 
|  5 |       2 | 
|  6 |       3 | 
+----+---------+

Table likes:
+----+---------+---------+
| id | post_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       3 |       2 |
|  2 |       3 |       1 |
|  3 |       4 |       1 |
|  4 |       1 |       3 |
+----+---------+---------+

Result wantend:
+---------+----------+
| post_id | username |
+---------+----------+
|       5 |        B |
|       6 |        C |
+---------+----------+
```

A problem I run into is that my query also returns `post_id: 3` because `user_id: 2` have liked the post.

I hope that you understands my question.

Thanks in Advance!
/Andreas

Comment: What is your query that you mention in the question?  Please edit the question with this query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach to the query that uses `not exists` for the `likes`:

```
select p.id as post_id, u.username
from posts p join
     users u
     on p.user_id = u.id
where not exists (select 1
                  from likes l
                  where l.post_id = p.id and l.user_id = 1
                 ) and
      u.id <> 1;
```

Comment: In some cases this answer produces way better results. It really depends on the database design and size.

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom here, I didn't realize I could do a WHERE using fields from the main query in the subquery!

Answer (score 8):

I think your data model isn't quite right, if "liking" a post adds a use to the "posts" table.

However, to answer your original question, you can exclude "liked" posts this way:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.user_id FROM 
    post p LEFT JOIN 
    likes l 
    ON p.post_id = l.post_id WHERE l.post_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is the answer. The others use subqueries, which are a significant performance hit and dangerous to use on a large database.

Comment: This is the Best answer! i am using similar approach on a huge data set with multiple joins. subqueries was taking 4.3900 seconds to execute where as this neat trick took only 1.2109 seconds which is a huge difference!

Comment: This is the right answer for most cases, but in rare cases the selected answer may produce significant improvement in performance, mostly when the join fields are not optimised.

Answer (score 3):

To find rows that don't have a match in another table, use a `LEFT JOIN` and then select the rows where the foreign key is `NULL`.

```
SELECT p.id as post_id, u.username
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.id AND l.user_id = 1
JOIN users u
WHERE u.id != 1 and l.post_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  p.id, u.username

FROM    stackoverflow.posts p
JOIN    stackoverflow.users u ON p.user_id = u.id

WHERE   user_id <> 1
        AND 
        p.id NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT  likes.post_id 

            FROM    stackoverflow.likes 

            WHERE   user_id = 1
        );
```